# Syntax highlighting not working in RVscode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have just started using R extension for vscode ([this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r)). I have installed as per the steps mentioned in the installation page (install R, I am using R4.1.1, then I installed languageserver, I also installed radian).

The issue I am facing is I am not getting any syntax highlighting, look at the example below:
[image]

What I want is the type of syntax highlighting as mentioned in the installation page. In the installation page, the function calls, function parameters etc are highlighted but that's not the case with my installation.

Comment: use a different theme, your strings have color, not of there own that is the syntax highlighting, maybe you have 2 TextMate grammars for R

Comment: Which installation page are you looking at that shows the syntax highlighting? Could you provide a link?